# How do you do fill_between two lines with different x-axis resolution?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am not sure if the title is clear enough (can't quite think of a better way to ask), but basically, I want to fill in a shaded area between the confines of two lines that form the standard deviation of a set of data. I have only 4 points on the x-axis for the data in the following example, but this is too coarse to allow for a smooth fill in of the two standard deviation lines.

It seems like I need to write some sort of extra set of codes to trace the y-axis value on a much finer set of x-axis points based on the existing standard deviation line (ie. maybe 10 extra points x 4 of the data sets?).

But I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of doing this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from scipy import stats

DataA = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
DataB = [2,6,4,8,9,10]
DataC = [6,3,5,7,9,19]
DataD = [9,10,13,12,11]

AllData = [DataA, DataB, DataC, DataD]
y1 = [np.mean(DataA), np.mean(DataB), np.mean(DataC), np.mean(DataD)]

x1 = np.arange(len(y1))

# Calculate SD for data
SDList = []
for SDCal in range(len(AllData)):
    SDList.append(np.std(AllData[SDCal], ddof=1))

plt.plot(x1, y1, color='red', linewidth=2, label = 'Data')

for SDFill in range(len(y1)):
    plt.fill_between([x1[SDFill]-0.5,x1[SDFill]+0.5], y1[SDFill]-SDList[SDFill], y1[SDFill]+SDList[SDFill],
        alpha=0.15, facecolor='#0042ff')

y1Lower = []
y1Higher = []

for sort in range(len(y1)):
    y1Higher.append(y1[sort] + SDList[sort])
    y1Lower.append(y1[sort] - SDList[sort])

plt.plot(x1, y1Lower, color='black', linestyle='dashed')
plt.plot(x1, y1Higher, color='black', linestyle='dashed', label = 'Std Dev')

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

The blue shaded region is the standard deviation of the corresponding data set. But how do I get the shaded region to fit into the two lines rather than as bars as shown?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the way you are calling `fill_between` inside a loop. You will get much better result if you just call `fill_between` with all your data in one call .

```
from scipy import stats

DataA = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
DataB = [2,6,4,8,9,10]
DataC = [6,3,5,7,9,19]
DataD = [9,10,13,12,11]

AllData = [DataA, DataB, DataC, DataD]
y1 = [np.mean(DataA), np.mean(DataB), np.mean(DataC), np.mean(DataD)]

x1 = np.arange(len(y1))

# Calculate SD for data
SDList = []
for SDCal in range(len(AllData)):
    SDList.append(np.std(AllData[SDCal], ddof=1))

plt.plot(x1, y1, color='red', linewidth=2, label = 'Data')

y1Lower = []
y1Higher = []

for sort in range(len(y1)):
    y1Higher.append(y1[sort] + SDList[sort])
    y1Lower.append(y1[sort] - SDList[sort])


plt.fill_between(x1, y1Lower, y1Higher,
    alpha=0.15, facecolor='#0042ff')

plt.plot(x1, y1Lower, color='black', linestyle='dashed')
plt.plot(x1, y1Higher, color='black', linestyle='dashed', label = 'Std Dev')

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```

[image]

BTW, your code can be much simplified if you use numpy arrays instead of lists:

```
from scipy import stats

DataA = [1,3,5,7,9,11]
DataB = [2,6,4,8,9,10]
DataC = [6,3,5,7,9,19]
DataD = [9,10,13,12,11]

AllData = [DataA, DataB, DataC, DataD]
y1 = np.array([np.mean(DataA), np.mean(DataB), np.mean(DataC), np.mean(DataD)])
x1 = np.arange(len(y1))

# Calculate SD for data
SDList = np.array([np.std(a) for a in AllData])

plt.plot(x1, y1, color='red', linewidth=2, label = 'Data')

plt.fill_between(x1, y1-SDList, y1+SDList,
    alpha=0.15, facecolor='#0042ff')

plt.plot(x1, y1-SDList, color='black', linestyle='dashed')
plt.plot(x1, y1+SDList, color='black', linestyle='dashed', label = 'Std Dev')

plt.legend(loc='best')

plt.show()
```